# Not able to extract attachments from notes document

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am trying to extract attachments present in richtext field of notes document.

Richtext field contains content(text) + attachments.

Tried to get handle of attachments  using doc.getfirstitem($file),  attached = Evaluate("@AttachmentNames", doc) ,but it returning as null (but attachments were present in document,able to open attachments manually from document).

Tried to get attachment count in view column(count is showing as 0), but attachments were present in document ($file is present).

Any suggestions how to get handle of attachments in document.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a chance that the document is storing rich text as MIME+HTML? If that's the case, then the "attachment" is just rich text content (a MIME part) until the document is open and converted to CD format.

Answer (score 0):

If your attachment is in a rich text field then look at http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/4aa88fb72e3c51f78525642e0075cdce?OpenDocument

Else use the same idea of the precedent example but access to all embedded object by:

```
 Forall o In doc.EmbeddedObjects
```